# Objective-C deserialize JSON into objects using JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

Is there a way using JSONModel library without inherit the JSONModel class.

I want to deserialized JSON to Objective C class without inherit form JSONModel.

Is there another library that deserialized JSON into objects without inheritance?

Comment: Is it possible that you want to use JSONModel with a class that extends from NSManagedObject?

Comment: Daij-Djan do you have an answer????

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a library for JSON Serialization in iOS. From iOS 5.0 onwards there is a class **NSJSONSerialization** is available for doing this.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html

Consider this code for converting list of contacts to json string

```
+(NSString*) jsonStringRepresentationOfSelectedReceiptients:(NSArray*) contactsList {
      NSMutableArray* contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      for (ContactObject *contactObj in contactsList) {
            NSDictionary* ltPair = @{@"phone_no": [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:contactObj.phoneNo, @"email_id": contactObj.emailId, @"display_name": contactObj.displayName]};
            [contactsArray addObject:ltPair];
      }
      NSData *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contactsArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
      NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"json string: %@", recptJson);
      return jsonString;
}
```

Hope this helps.
(I gave ios specific answer because tags are related to iOS.

Comment: My mistake, I want to deserialize from json to object. My object contain many properties (some of them are other objects). Is there a class is available for this?

Comment: Check my another answer about de-serialization of json string to NSDictionary/NSArray using NSJsonSerialization class.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS5 onwards you can use NSJSONSerialization class for serializing as well as deserializing. For deserialization, you want to first convert your json string to an NSData object, and call the class method JSONObjectWithData

```
NSData *jsonData = [myJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&error];
```

Using isKindOfClass you can find out if this is an dictionary or array because  JSONObjectWithData will return either an NSDictionary or an NSArray, depending whether your JSON string represents an a dictionary or an array.

Comment: how do you convert NSDictionary dict to my object?

Comment: You can use something like myobj.email = [dict objectForKey:@"email"]; Do this for all of properties. The key in mydict will be the from json. (U sud use dynamic properties for ur object)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to inherit from JSONModel?

The thing is that when you inherit from JSONModel you are inheriting all the tools of the library. It's intended to be used like that because the methods that the library exposes are not static so you need to have instances derived from JSONModel.

Comment: i don't want to inherit because my class will be attached to Json only, and maybe someday i would like to deserialize xml to my class object